# JavaScript how to creating dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables

I am trying to create dynamic variable, for example rather saying

```
let f0, f1 = '';
```

and then using these variable in forEach

```
{Object.keys(shop).forEach((element, key) => {
              if (element == dName[0]) {
                f0 = Object.values(shop)[key];
              }           
              if (element == dName[1]) {
                f1 = Object.values(shop)[key];
              }
            })}
```

trying below,

```
let k = 'f'; 
    let i = 0; 
    for(i = 1; i < 2; i++) { 
        eval('let ' + k + i + '= \'\' ;'); 
    } 
    console.log("f1=" + f1);
```

but console printing

> f1=undefined

```
what wrong I am doing, thanks in advance
```

Comment: Why would you do this? It negatively affects security, performance, readability, maintainability, and you don't need it. If you want dynamic identifiers, use an object with computed property names

Comment: Just don't do that, please. Don't use `eval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i don't know if it is possible with eval but you could use an object to store your variables like this

```
let k = 'f'
let vars = {}

for(i = 1; i < 5; i++) { 
  vars[k+i] = '' 
} 
console.log(vars)
console.log("f1=" + vars.f1);
```